# How does `unicode-math` correct super-/sub-script positioning?

Tags: subscripts, superscripts, unicode-math, opentype

From my understanding, `unicode-math` primarily relies on the data in the OpenType `MATH` table to properly typeset each font. However, in most of the OpenType fonts I have examined (including the ones recommended by the `unicode-math` package), there is no "math kerning table" which contains the positioning adjustments necessary to properly nestle subscripts comfortably for each glyph. I have since discovered that Microsoft [patented](http://www.google.com/patents/US7492366) the process of using the data in this table to perform such kerning, which would explain why free fonts avoid providing such a table.

However, for the most part `unicode-math` manages to position these scripts just fine. How is this performed?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Do you have a reference for your information about kerning patents?

Comment: @Thruston Yes, Microsoft's patent (filed in 2005) can be found [here](http://www.google.com/patents/US7492366).

Comment: Thanks!  Interesting but not very readable!

Comment: @Thurston For sure, and US patent law is a very complicated topic. I am considering asking a patent attorney about that patent, because I suspect it may fail the non-obvious/novelty requirement (from what I can gather from reading it, their advanced method of correcting script placement... is to move the script to the left). Which I think is what TeX has been doing for a long time :P